# Android Studio is shown 'is not translated in ...'

Tags: android-studio

Sorry my English is not nice.

I'm using Android studio. Android studio shown '... is not translated in jp' everything.

But I did not use Japanese language, and I'm not had values-ja folder and file.

Why it is find empty file?

- I tried 'Build>clean Project'  but result not fixed.
- I tried 'Build>Rebuild project' and not fixed bug.

Code:

```
    <resources>
            <string name="app_name">Test</string>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem! It use jp language in sub module.
I deleted sub module jp language file and folder.

so not display '... is not translated in ...' message.